# id value get on the same page php

Tags: php

I want to show a particular row history and for this i want to get an id of a particular row which i am getting succefully like this:

```
http://localhost/Users/Operator/History.php#?id=111
```

But the problem is that, i want to get this id on the same page which i am unable to get i.e

```
echo "IK".$_GET["id"]; // error: undefined index
```

If i access this id on another page, i am getting the id successfully with `$_GET["id"]`. Any help would be appreciated:

button to click on  particular row - code:

```
<td><a href="#?id='.$row["FIR_NO"].'" id="showpopup" class="button blue" style="border-radius: 20px 20px 20px 20px">
          <div class="icon">
                   <span class="ico-pop-out"></span>
          </div>
    </a>
</td>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable can be accessed only by Javascript , you cannot capture it via PHP.

The parameter that is preceded by `#` will never reach the server-side script.

Comment: how can i do that? any help?

Comment: Just pass it like this.. remove the `#`  `http://localhost/Users/Operator/History.php?id=111`

Comment: By doing that i am unable to go to my popup part. I will try after i resolve my issue and will let you know. thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `#` from the link, everything after the # stays on client-side

Comment: By doing that i am unable to go to my popup part. I will try after i resolve my issue and will let you know. thankyou.